# Need to create a Vtiger 6.1 custom module

Tags: module, relation, vtiger

I need to create a Vtiger 6.1 custom module, that will be in relation with Organisation module, with list view on Organisation details page.
I couldn't find any documentation for such situation, all I found was a basic custom module structure with very limited and standalone functionality.
Can anyone suggest anything please.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Module Designer for making custom module. 
Below link helps you to create custom module. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PF3noyh7M-g